# Trouble pinpointing source of uninitialized value

Tags: c++, initialization, embedded-linux, valgrind

I am writing a simple earthquake detection program for the BeagleBone Green using a vibration sensor that I have hooked up, together with a cape that has a built in accelerometer and digit display. The brains of the earthquake detector are located in the `EarthquakeDetector` class.

`earthquake_detector.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

#include <Accelerometer/accelerometer.h>
#include <DigitDisplay/digit_display.h>
#include <VibrationSensor/vibration_sensor.h>

namespace earthquake_detection_unit {

class EarthquakeDetector {
public:
    EarthquakeDetector();
    ~EarthquakeDetector();

private:
    // Worker thread for continuous earthquake monitoring.
    void Worker();

    // Monitors accelerometer readings. This function returns after a certain 
    // number of consecutive low readings.
    void AccelerometerMonitor();

    // Displays current magnitude on the digit display.
    void DisplayMagnitude();

    // Worker thread member variable.
    std::thread worker_thread;
    // Signal to shutdown worker thread.
    std::atomic<bool> shutdown;

    // Pointers to devices.
    Accelerometer *accelerometer;
    DigitDisplay *digit_display;
    VibrationSensor *vibration_sensor;
};

} // earthquake_detection_unit
```

`earthquake_detector.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "earthquake_detector.h"

namespace earthquake_detection_unit {

const double kScaleValue1Threshold = 0.144;
const double kScaleValue2Threshold = 0.281;
const double kScaleValue3Threshold = 0.418;
const double kScaleValue4Threshold = 0.555;
const double kScaleValue5Threshold = 0.692;
const double kScaleValue6Threshold = 0.829;
const double kScaleValue7Threshold = 0.966;
const double kScaleValue8Threshold = 1.103;
const double kScaleValue9Threshold = 1.24;

const int kAccelerometerTimeoutTotal_ms = 10000;
const int kAccelerometerSamplePeriod_ms = 100;
const int kAccelerometerTimeoutNumPeriods = kAccelerometerTimeoutTotal_ms / kAccelerometerSamplePeriod_ms;

EarthquakeDetector::EarthquakeDetector() : shutdown(false) {
    // Initialize digit display.
    digit_display = new DigitDisplay();

    worker_thread = std::thread(&EarthquakeDetector::Worker, this);
}

EarthquakeDetector::~EarthquakeDetector() {
    shutdown.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    worker_thread.join();

    // Shutdown digit display.
    delete digit_display;
}

void EarthquakeDetector::Worker() {
    while (!shutdown) {
        std::cout << "\t<EarthquakeDetector> ";
        std::cout << "Launching vibration sensor to listen for a vibration." << std::endl;
        // First, wait for a vibration.
        vibration_sensor = new VibrationSensor();
        vibration_sensor->WaitForVibration();
        delete vibration_sensor;

        // After detecting a vibration, launch accelerometer.
        std::cout << "\t<EarthquakeDetector> ";
        std::cout << "Vibration detected -- vibration sensor shutdown, launching accelerometer." << std::endl;
        accelerometer = new Accelerometer();

        // Monitor accelerometer readings.
        AccelerometerMonitor();

        // Flash magnitude.
        digit_display->FlashDisplay();
        // Reset digit display to display 0.
        digit_display->SetDigit(0);

        // Shutdown accelerometer for lack of activity.
        std::cout << "\t<EarthquakeDetector> ";
        std::cout << "Shutting down accelerometer due to inactivity." << std::endl;
        delete accelerometer;
    }
}

void EarthquakeDetector::AccelerometerMonitor() {
    // This function returns if we obtain kAccelerometerTimeoutNumPeriods
    // consecutive low readings from the accelerometer.
    int consecutive_readings = 0;
    while (consecutive_readings != kAccelerometerTimeoutNumPeriods) {
        DisplayMagnitude();
        if (accelerometer->GetCurrentReading() >= kScaleValue1Threshold) {
            consecutive_readings = 0;
        }
        else {
            ++consecutive_readings;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(kAccelerometerSamplePeriod_ms));
    }
}

void EarthquakeDetector::DisplayMagnitude() {
    double acc_reading = accelerometer->GetHighestReading();

    unsigned int digit_to_display = 0;
    if (acc_reading >= kScaleValue9Threshold) {
        digit_to_display = 9;
    }
    else if (acc_reading >= kScaleValue8Threshold) {
        digit_to_display = 8;
    }
    else if (acc_reading >= kScaleValue7Threshold) {
        digit_to_display = 7;
    }
    else if (acc_reading >= kScaleValue6Threshold) {
        digit_to_display = 6;
    }
    else if (acc_reading >= kScaleValue5Threshold) {
        digit_to_display = 5;
    }
    else if (acc_reading >= kScaleValue4Threshold) {
        digit_to_display = 4;
    }
    else if (acc_reading >= kScaleValue3Threshold) {
        digit_to_display = 3;
    }
    else if (acc_reading >= kScaleValue2Threshold) {
        digit_to_display = 2;
    }
    else if (acc_reading >= kScaleValue1Threshold) {
        digit_to_display = 1;
    }

    digit_display->SetDigit(digit_to_display);
}

} // earthquake_detection_unit
```

**Problem:** Valgrind complains about an unitialized unsigned int (I used the `--track-origins=yes` option) and I can't find where I could possibly have an unitialized value in my implementation. I get the following error several times, presumably because as the code is being executed, it's falling through the line of if-statements in `DisplayMagnitude`.

```
==1023== Thread 2:
==1023== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1023==    at 0x10A2DA: earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::DisplayMagnitude() (earthquake_detector.cc:85)
==1023==    by 0x10A227: earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::AccelerometerMonitor() (earthquake_detector.cc:70)
==1023==    by 0x10A15B: earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::Worker() (earthquake_detector.cc:51)
==1023==    by 0x10B705: void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*>(std::__invoke_memfun_deref, void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*&&)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*&&) (invoke.h:73)
==1023==    by 0x10B633: std::__invoke_result<void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*>::type std::__invoke<void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*>(void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*&&)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*&&) (invoke.h:95)
==1023==    by 0x10B5A1: void std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*> >::_M_invoke<0u, 1u>(std::_Index_tuple<0u, 1u>) (thread:244)
==1023==    by 0x10B53F: std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*> >::operator()() (thread:251)
==1023==    by 0x10B515: std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*> > >::_M_run() (thread:195)
==1023==    by 0x48FAA69: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
==1023==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==1023==    at 0x4840194: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:415)
==1023==    by 0x10A147: earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::Worker() (earthquake_detector.cc:48)
==1023==    by 0x10B705: void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*>(std::__invoke_memfun_deref, void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*&&)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*&&) (invoke.h:73)
==1023==    by 0x10B633: std::__invoke_result<void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*>::type std::__invoke<void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*>(void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*&&)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*&&) (invoke.h:95)
==1023==    by 0x10B5A1: void std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*> >::_M_invoke<0u, 1u>(std::_Index_tuple<0u, 1u>) (thread:244)
==1023==    by 0x10B53F: std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*> >::operator()() (thread:251)
==1023==    by 0x10B515: std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector::*)(), earthquake_detection_unit::EarthquakeDetector*> > >::_M_run() (thread:195)
==1023==    by 0x48FAA69: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
```

I'm wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of what could possibly be causing these errors. I have looked at various SO posts on similar issues but nothing really seemed to apply to my situation. Thanks!

**Edit 1:** Stripped down version of the accelerometer interface. I edited out a lot of the I2C file reading and writing to make this as brief as possible.

`accelerometer.h`:

```
namespace earthquake_detection_unit {

class Accelerometer {
public:
    typedef struct Vector {
        Vector(int16_t x_reading, int16_t y_reading, int16_t z_reading);

        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
        double magnitude;
    } Vector;

    Accelerometer();
    ~Accelerometer();

    inline double GetCurrentReading() { return current_reading; }
    inline double GetHighestReading() { return highest_reading; }

private:
    // Worker thread for sampling accelerometer readings.
    void Worker();

    void CollectReading();

    void ActivateAccelerometer();
    void ShutDownAccelerometer();

    // Signal to shutdown worker thread.
    std::atomic<bool> shutdown;
    // Worker thread.
    std::thread worker_thread;
    // Exponentially smoothed accelerometer magnitude reading.
    std::atomic<double> current_reading;
    // Highest reading detected by accelerometer.
    std::atomic<double> highest_reading;
};

} // earthquake_detection_unit
```

`accelerometer.cc`:

```
namespace earthquake_detection_unit {

Accelerometer::Accelerometer() {
    std::atomic<bool> shutdown(false);
    std::atomic<double> current_reading(0.0f);
    std::atomic<double> highest_reading(0.0f);

    // Activate accelerometer using I2C.
    ActivateAccelerometer();

    worker_thread = std::thread(&Accelerometer::Worker, this);
}

Accelerometer::~Accelerometer() {
    shutdown = true;
    worker_thread.join();
    // Shut down accelerometer via I2C.
    ShutDownAccelerometer();
}

Accelerometer::Vector::Vector(int16_t x_reading, int16_t y_reading, int16_t z_reading) {
    // Omitted: constructs Vector object containing accelerations and magnitude.
}

void Accelerometer::Worker() {
    while (!shutdown) {
        CollectReading();
        if (current_reading > highest_reading) {
            highest_reading.store(current_reading, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        }

        // Gather samples every 2 ms.
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(kSleepTime_ms));
    }
}

void Accelerometer::CollectReading() {
    // Omitted: collect accelerometer sample and store it in
    //          latest_vector_reading.
    Vector latest_vector_reading(x_reading, y_reading, z_reading);

    double latest_magnitude_reading = latest_vector_reading.magnitude;

    current_reading.store(kSmoothingFactor * latest_magnitude_reading +
                          (1.0f - kSmoothingFactor) * current_reading,
                          std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

} // earthquake_detection_unit
```

Comment: I suppose it doesn't like that the accelerometer is initialised in `Worker` and not the constructor?

Comment: @beothunder Do you mean I should initialize the accelerometer pointer to nullptr in the constructor? I will try that, however, it does not seem to complain about the vibration sensor.

Comment: The vibrator sensor is not used across functions.

Comment: Initializing ``accelerometer`` pointer to ``nullptr`` in the constructor did not get rid of the Valgrind errors.

Comment: Of course. It's a pointer. And in `DisplayMagnitude` you are dereferencing it: `accelerometer->GetHighestReading();`. Initializing the pointer to 0 does nothing.

Comment: You should try moving all `new`s and `delete`s (for the accelerometer and vibrator) to the constructor and the destructor respectively.

Comment: 1. You could pass the pointer as an argument, or move the new and delete to the function where you are using that pointer. You should probably also remove the pointers that do not share the lifetime with `EarthquakeDetector` from the class. 2. The pointer is initialized. But it points to uninitialized memory [0x0000]. (response to deleted comment)

Comment: It would really be good if you could strip this down to a [mcve].  For instance, I'm wondering if `accelerometer->GetCurrentReading()` or `accelerometer->GetHighestReading()` might be reading a member of `*accelerometer` that its constructor didn't initialize.  But you didn't show us the source for the `Accelerometer` class and its methods, and if it's as long as `class EarthQuakeDetector` then this is going to be a lot to read through unless you can reduce it substantially.

Comment: (Even though it says the offending access is from `DisplayMagnitude()`, it very well could actually be in `GetHighestReading()` which may have been inlined.  valgrind can't necessarily tell the difference.)

Comment: @beothunder yeah I deleted the comment as I realized I could write methods to start up and shut down the accelerometer (so start up and shut down are outside of the constructor/destructor). That way I technically construct the accelerometer once, but turn it on and off whenever it's needed.

Comment: It looks to me that you aren't building with debug information (-g). Could you try that and post the memcheck error stanza with line numbers?

Comment: @NateEldredge I edited the post to add some more context as to how the ``Accelerometer`` class works if you are still curious. From my understanding, all of its fields are properly initialized in the constructor. Obviously this isn't complete, but I really don't see a way to post a compiling program here while also maintaining any level of brevity.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Updated the post to show a sample of the error messages that come up when compiled with -g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken your problem is your constructor

```
Accelerometer::Accelerometer() {
    std::atomic<bool> shutdown(false);
    std::atomic<double> current_reading(0.0f);
    std::atomic<double> highest_reading(0.0f);

    // Activate accelerometer using I2C.
    ActivateAccelerometer();

    worker_thread = std::thread(&Accelerometer::Worker, this);
}
```

In the above `highest_reading` is a local variable that hides the variable of the same name at class scope. You are initializing this local variable and leaving the class member uninitialized.

Try something like

```
Accelerometer::Accelerometer() : shutdown(false), current_reading(0.0), highest_reading(0.0) {
    // Activate accelerometer using I2C.
    ActivateAccelerometer();

    worker_thread = std::thread(&Accelerometer::Worker, this);
}
```

I'm using an initializer list, generally the preferred way of initializing class members.